# Can't add duplicate row to the asp.net Table Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net table control like this:

```
  TableHeader
A Text | Textbox
```

What I want to do is, in the page_load event, duplicate second row with all the controls within it, change the text in the first cell and add as a new row. So here is my code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < loop1counter; i++)
        {
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            row = myTable.Rows[1]; //Duplicate original row
            char c = (char)(66 + i);
            if (c != 'M')
            {
                row.Cells[0].Text = c.ToString();
                myTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
```

But when I execute this code it justs overwrites on the original row and row count of the table doesn't change. Thanks for help....

Answer (score 2):

As thekip mentioned, you are re-writing the reference.
Create a new row. Add it to the grid and then copy the cell values in whatever manner you want.
Something like:

```
TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
myTable.Rows.Add(tRow);
foreach (TableCell cell in myTable.Rows[1].Cells)
{
    TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
    tCell.Text = cell.Text;
    tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
 }
```

Comment: but this code just copies the text attribute, in my cells I have Textboxes and FilteredTextBoxExtender(ajaxToolkits) I have to clone them too...

Answer (score 1):

It gets overwritten because you overwrite the reference. You don't do a copy, essentially the `row = new TableRow()` is doing nothing.

You should use
`myTable.ImportRow(myTable.Rows[1])`.

Adjusted based on response try:
`row = myTable.Rows[1].MemberwiseClone();`

Comment: I couldn't find the ImportRow method. I am using ASP.net Table Control

Comment: you can access MemberwiseClone in context of a derived class or within that class itself only.

Answer (score 0):

so try this

```
private TableRow CopyTableRow(TableRow row)
{

    TableRow newRow = new TableRow();
    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        TableCell tempCell = new TableCell();
        foreach (Control ctrl in cell.Controls)
        {
            tempCell.Controls.Add(ctrl);
        }
        tempCell.Text = cell.Text;
        newRow.Cells.Add(tempCell);
    }
    return newRow;
}
```

your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < loop1counter; i++)
    {
        TableRow row = CopyTableRow(myTable.Rows[1]); //Duplicate original row
        char c = (char)(66 + i);
        if (c != 'M')
        {
            row.Cells[0].Text = c.ToString();
            myTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
```